# Dúvida jogo dois jogadores, metade da tela de cabeça para baixo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment, jogos

Estou criando um programa para praticar o que aprendi até o momento e aprender mais, porém cheguei à um empasse. A dúvida é a seguinte:

Estou criando um joguinho de pergunta e resposta para dois jogadores, cada um fica de um lado do celular para jogar, o *layout* desejado seria algo como a foto abaixo:

[image: meu_layout]

Mas eu não sei como fazer para fazer aquela metade de cima (parte amarela) ficar com as coisas aparecendo de **cabeça para baixo**, tem algum jeito de usar um *fragment* e rotacionar ele? Ou alguma ideia pessoal?

Detalhe, as duas partes podem ser iguais, só que a de cima de cabeça para baixo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sugiro usar esse *custom layout*: [Rotate Layout](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1929)

Seu uso de acordo com o criador é bastante simples, basta arrumar no seu `gradle`

o **repositório**:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

e a **dependência**:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'rongi.rotate-layout:rotate-layout:2.0.0'
}
```

feito isso, arrume no seu `layout` as linhas a seguir:

```
<com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_content"
    android:layout_height="match_content"
    app:angle="180"> <!-- Nessa linha o angulo que você deseja -->

    <LinearLayout <!-- Aqui altere pelo seu layout -->
        android:layout_width="match_content"
        android:layout_height="match_content">
    </LinearLayout>

</com.github.rongi.rotate_layout.layout.RotateLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Consegui pessoal, achei bem pouco conteúdo sobre isso, mas é algo bem básico, apenas dividi a tela em dois RelativeLayouts e usei um simples atributo do xml, o   android:rotation="180"
Segue abaixo como ficou o código.
(Acho que ficaria melhor se tivesse usado dois fragments, mas ainda estou aprendendo a usa-los)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Relative1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFF111"
    android:rotation="180">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonP2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pergunta:"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPergunta2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Placar"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlacar2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Relative2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#FF0000">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/buttonP1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Pergunta:"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPergunta1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Placar"
        android:id="@+id/textViewPlacar1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que cada parte terá uma funcionalidade individualmente certo ? Você pode usar uma activity, e popular ela com dois fragments, depois você específica a orientação de cada fragment. Essa [questão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19385014/6404635) (em inglês) mostra como forçar uma orientação da tela.

Edit (Conteúdo do link):

Você pode especificar programaticamente qual a orientação da tela que deseja, basta colocar `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`  ou `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);` para travar a tela de ponta cabeça.

Os outros fragmentos que não serão "travados", devem conter `getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);` desta forma, permanece com a configuração inicial.